# Ubuntu 12.04 - Network Manager Problem In System Tray

Tags: 12.04, networking, network-manager, gnome-classic

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I installed fallback version of desktop. I have a problem about my network manager in system tray. I can see network manager but no button is working in network manager in system tray.

[image: Network Manager]

I could not make buttons in network manager as seen in the image worked.

What can be the solution of this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: So you can't click on any of those buttons? Can you open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `sudo service network-manager restart`, and check again?

Comment: They are still not working. I can clicked but there is no reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting the applet:

```
killall nm-applet
nm-applet &
```

Answer (score 0):

After numerous attempts to fix the issue,I resorted to installing an application "Wicd Network Manager" available in the Software Center.Works pretty neat.